# Restore primary key in active record schema

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

Somehow, my schema ended up with this id column:

```
create_table "tables", :id => false, :force => true do |t|
    t.integer  "id",                                         :null => false
    # other fieds
  end
```

This is the info on the column (note that primary is false):

```
[4] pry(main)> Table.columns.first
=> #<ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::PostgreSQLColumn:0x007f98d06cc0f8
 @coder=nil,
 @default=nil,
 @limit=nil,
 @name="id",
 @null=false,
 @precision=nil,
 @primary=false,
 @scale=nil,
 @sql_type="integer",
 @type=:integer>
```

So I get this error whenever I try to save a new record:
`ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::Error: ERROR:  null value in column "id" violates not-null constraint`

What's the best way to restore my primary key?

Comment: Can you explain a little bit more into detail how this happened? 
You created a table without a `id` and then wanted to add one?

Comment: I have no idea how it happened.  I looked through the migrations and nowhere does it explicitly set the id field for this table.

Comment: and now you want to remove it?

Comment: also, you might wanna rethink about about having the table name `tables` since it may be in the reserved keywords for postgres. Maybe someone with more experience will say something more about it

Comment: The name "tables" is just a fake name for this question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rails migrations can't handle this natively - you'll need to use `execute` with the SQL that sets the primary key, creates the missing sequence, moves the sequence to the latest 'id' value (if any are present), and assigns the sequence nextval as the default:

```
execute("ALTER TABLE tables ADD PRIMARY KEY (id);")
execute("CREATE sequence tables_id_seq;")

# skip this next line if you know that no rows exist yet
execute("SELECT setval('tables_id_seq', (SELECT MAX(id) FROM tables));")    

execute("ALTER TABLE tables ALTER id SET DEFAULT nextval('tables_id_seq');")
```

Comment: Dang.  It says PG::Error: ERROR:  relation "tables_id_seq" already exists.

Comment: @DavidNix: Aha, so it must have been a primary key at one point.  In that case just skip the second line `execute("CREATE sequence...`.